# Is there a way to poll buttons for clicks in a Team card?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Need a way to see which button was clicked on a Team card without a callback. Is there a way (either with the messages endpoint, or any other) that would allow us to query that message for actions?

I can create messages with this endpoint...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

And it looks like I can create buttons using this...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#adaptive-card

But I'm not sure how to get the results of the button pushes without doing a callback of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

The action performed in response to an Action on an adaptive card is dictated by the developer. Specifically in Teams, you can have a new section of the card displayed, the browser open to a page or have an activity sent to the bot.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-actions

Comment: So that sort of answers my question...all of those require a callback of some sort. There's not a way to poll that card via the Graph API and say, hey card, was this button pushed, if so, give me some data?

Comment: I would not use the word callback in this scenario.  Your bot is a web service, and the bot service calls your web service in response to actions from the users.

If you wish to get chat messages from Microsoft Graph, you can use the beta endpoint. But keep in mind that some of the actions in an adaptive card will not write data to the chat/message history.

Comment: Yea, to be specific, I'm not writing a traditional Bot. Due to network constraints I can only use the graph API.